# MVC immediate validation is not triggering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form in MVC 5. I have three drop-downs on my form which are required. When i submit the form, the error message appears. The problem is that, when i select the value from drop-down, the error messages still show. And then if i submit the button, required error message disappears.

The main problem is that immediate validation not working. This scenario occurs when i first submit the form without selection and then i select the drop down value. The error still show.
Here is my Form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProcessId)


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 bgnMrgn">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h3>@Resources.BasicInformtion</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
            <label class="control-label">Intiqal Type</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Intiqal.IntiqalTypeId, new SelectList(Model.IntiqalTypes, "IntiqalTypeId", "IntiqalTypeName"), Resources.Select, new { id = "intiqalTypes", Class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Intiqal.IntiqalTypeId, "", new { id = "", @class = "text-danger" })



        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
            <label class="control-label">Source</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Intiqal.ProcessInitiationTypeId, new SelectList(new List<ProcessInitiationType>
            (), "ProcessInitiationTypeId", "ProcessInitiationTypeName"), Resources.Select, new { id = "processInitiationTypes", Class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Intiqal.ProcessInitiationTypeId, "", new { id = "", @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-2 hidden" id="shamilatSelection">
            <label class="control-label">Shamilat</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Intiqal.Shamilat, new SelectList(Model.Shamilat, "Key", "Value"), Resources.Select, new { id = "shamilat", Class = "form-control " })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Intiqal.Shamilat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//Other stuff including submit button
    }
```

What's the problem?

EDITED -- Here is the script Order

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in the view or layout?

Comment: Yes, i have in my layout. I view page source. It is included.

Comment: Best guess is its not loaded correctly, because the form would not submit if it was working. Is it in order - `jquery` then `jquery.validate` then `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`? Either that of you have disabled client side validation

Comment: @StephenMuecke i edited the question with script order. Please see.

Comment: That looks fine. Are you sure you have not included any duplicates in the view?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I seem to wrestle with in almost every single MVC project I create.

The problem, presumably, is that you either are not loading (or loading in the wrong order, etc) the jquery-validation-unobtrusive.js (or .min.js) for that form.

I typically make sure it is added to my ScriptBundle package so unobtrusive validation works on every page.

In many cases, I have been forced to uninstall-package and the install-package again for the jquery unobtrusive validation package.

Aside from that, on pages with forms I usually throw one of these at the bottom:

```
@section Scripts 
{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And ensure your web.config contains the following:

```
 <appSettings>
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added my bundle in layout and include in my every form. Every form is working fine except this one.

Comment: Ooo one other thing...is there any chance that the unobtrusive works on the 3rd dropdown and not the other 2?  The only other difference I see (assuming the jquery and validation orders are all kosher--I always mess it up) is that dropdowns 1 & 2 are dynamically generated at runtime--so maybe unobtrusive doesn't have the values to validate against?  I'm not  sure how that would affect them being required..I think I need to go to bed

Comment: All three drop downs not working but there is one drop down dynamically generated.